# How to use flashlight/torch with Google Vision barcode reader API?

Tags: android, google-play-services, barcode-scanner, flashlight, google-vision

I have a similar question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654087/how-turn-on-flashlight-using-barcode-detection-in-google-play-services) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811411/accessing-autofocus-flash-with-google-vision-barcode-reader), neither of which have an accepted solution.

I'm basically using the Google Vision barcode API but there appears no obvious way to control the flashlight.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32659445/1617737) suggests using [this code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java), but (having tried and failed) I'm not sure how to integrate it into my app.

Here is the code for my activity, which basically starts the camera/barcode scanner and also uses a menu item from my `BaseActivity` which I want to use to be able to toggle the flashlight:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ScanQRCodeAutoActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = ScanQRCodeAutoActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int CAMERA_SOURCE_PREVIEW_WIDTH = -1;
    private static final int CAMERA_SOURCE_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 480;
    public static final String QR_CODE_VALUE = "QR_CODE_VALUE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_qr_code_auto);

        super.initFlash(savedInstanceState);

        final SurfaceView cameraSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraSurfaceView);

        BarcodeDetector.Builder barcodeDetectorBuilder = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this);
        barcodeDetectorBuilder.setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE);
        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = barcodeDetectorBuilder.build();
        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {

                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

                if (barcodes.size() != 0) {

                    Intent data = new Intent();
                    data.putExtra(QR_CODE_VALUE, barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                    setResult(CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS, data);
                    finish();

                }

            }
        });

        CameraSource.Builder cameraSourceBuilder = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector);
        //cameraSourceBuilder.setAutoFocusEnabled(true);
        //cameraSourceBuilder.setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        if (CAMERA_SOURCE_PREVIEW_WIDTH != -1 && CAMERA_SOURCE_PREVIEW_HEIGHT != -1) {
            cameraSourceBuilder.setRequestedPreviewSize(CAMERA_SOURCE_PREVIEW_WIDTH, CAMERA_SOURCE_PREVIEW_HEIGHT);
        }

        final CameraSource cameraSource = cameraSourceBuilder.build();

        cameraSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                try {
                    cameraSource.start(cameraSurfaceView.getHolder());

                }
                catch (SecurityException se) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not start camera source.", se);
                }
                catch (IOException ioe) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Couldn't start camera source.", ioe);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                cameraSource.stop();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuItem flashItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_flash);
        flashItem.setVisible(true);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void toggleFlash() {

        super.toggleFlash();

        // HELP!!

        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        if (isFlashOn()) {
            Utilities.makeToast(this, "Flash turned on");
        }
        else {
            Utilities.makeToast(this, "Flash turned off");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this ? I am also facing the same issue :(

Comment: In the end, I think I used another library - like ZXing.

Comment: still not any solution for this?

Comment: I think I used another library in the end. It's been a long time since I looked at it, but maybe Google Vision has it sussed now?